# Why does my CSS code not work on the headings on my site?

Tags: css, css-selectors, responsive

I want the headings on my site to be responsive. It's not something the theme provides unfortunately,so i'm going to have to use CSS.

I've used the following:

```
@media (max-width: 365px) {
    porto-u-heading {
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 0.5;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }}

@media (max-width: 365px) 
{   porto-u-sub-heading { 
      font-size: 30px; 
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, it's not working on my site: https://wordpress-588666-1906106.cloudwaysapps.com/

Can anybody help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: porto-u-heading its selector by tag, .porto-u-heading is selector by class, what do you want?

Comment: I would rather use the selector by class. But tried both... tag "h1" and "porto-sub-heading... Both not working. Saw I forgot the . in .porto-sub-heading.. Added it now but nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, use a dot in front of class names for the selectors: `.porto-u-heading { ... }`

Comment: Thanks! I added the . to the CSS. It's still not working. I also tried with "h1", but that's also not working....